# Python testing raw input, raw input in if statement

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm currently testing my python code and have a question about raw_input. This is my function:

```
def answer():
    ans = raw_input('enter yes or no')
    if ans == 'yes':
        print 'you entered yes'
        return 'yes'
    if ans == 'no':
        some_value = raw_input('enter some value: ')
        print 'you entered no'
        return some_value
```

I'm testing the first if statement this way:

```
with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', return_value= 'yes'):
    assert answer() == 'yes'
```

But how do I check the no statement ? How do I make mock inside a mock ?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`side_effect`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect):

```
with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', side_effect=['yes']):
    assert answer() == 'yes'
with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', side_effect=['no', 'maybe']):
    assert answer() == 'maybe'
```

According to [`mock` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#calling):

> If `side_effect` is an iterable then each call to the mock will return the next value from the iterable.
>   The side_effect can also be any iterable object. Repeated calls to the mock will return values from the iterable (until the iterable is exhausted and a StopIteration is raised):
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> m = MagicMock(side_effect=[1, 2, 3])
> >>> m()
> 1
> >>> m()
> 2
> >>> m()
> 3
> >>> m()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ...
> StopIteration
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using side effect should do the trick, I find the following quite clear and avoid multiple with-block:

```
def my_side_effect(*args):  # each argument will be the return_value of one call
    for el in args:
        yield el  # we use a generator to return different value each time

with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input') as mocked:  # here the mocked object is accessible in the block
    mocked.side_effect = my_side_effect('yes')  # here one call that return 'yes'
    assert answer() == 'yes'
    mocked.side_effect = my_side_effect('no', 'maybe')  # two calls, the first return 'no', the second 'maybe'
    assert answer() == 'maybe'
```

Comment: I didn't realize `side_effect` could take a generator like this. Generators are always the easiest way to bundle up simple state. +1, only because I can't +10.

Answer (score 0):

If you just mock `raw_input` to return `'no'`, it will return `'no'` both times, meaning you can assert that the function returns `'no'`:

```
with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', return_value='yes'):
    assert answer() == 'yes'
with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', return_value='no'):
    assert answer() == 'no'
```

If you want to test what happens if, say, the first input is `'no'` and the second one is `'maybe'`, you have to mock it with a function that returns different things the first time it's called and the second time it's called, and then you can assert that it returns `'maybe'`. Something like this (not tested because I don't have `mock` installed here… but it should give you the idea):

```
def fake_raw_input(once=[False]):
    if not once[0]:
        once[0] = True
        return 'no'
    return 'maybe'

with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', return_value='yes'):
    assert answer() == 'yes'
with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', new_callable=fake_raw_input):
    assert answer() == 'maybe'
```